# How call inner join in SvcClient entites?

Tags: c#, linq, web-services

How to insert join enties when we call webservice calls?

```
SELECT 
      distinct [COMMITTEE_MAST_CUST]      
  FROM [PDEV].[dbo].[COM_COMMITTEE_MEMBER] cc Inner join CUSTOMER c 
  on c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = cc.COMMITTEE_MAST_CUST
  where MEMBER_MAST_CUST = '0827857' and cc.END_DATE > GETDATE()  
 and c.CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE IN ('SECTION_OFFICER','CHAPTER_OFFICER')
```

But now doing now this don't have clue where to put join in this using above query.

```
SvcClient.Client.Context.ComCommittees.Where(x => x.MemberMasterCustomer 
        == masterCustomerId  && x.EndDate > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your contexts are being defined (does SvcClient.Client.Context.ComCommittees correspond to [PDEV].[dbo].[COM_COMMITTEE_MEMBER]?) but I believe you would put the .Join before the .Where clause.

Something like this:

```
SvcClient.Client.Context.ComCommittees.Join(Customer, mast => id.COMMITTEE_MAST_CUST, cust=>cust.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID, (mast, cust) => new { cc = mast, c = cust }).Where(x => x.MemberMasterCustomer 
        == masterCustomerId  && x.EndDate > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3)).ToList();
```

Although you should consider writing it in query syntax:

```
var myResult = (from cc in SvcClient.Client.Context.ComCommittees
join customer in CustomerContext on cc.COMMITTEE_MAST_CUST equals customer.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
where (cc.MemberMasterCustomer == masterCustomerId) && (cc.EndDate > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3))).ToList()
```

(I wasn't sure on some of your variable names but this is the basic jist)

Comment: What about this c.CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE IN ('SECTION_OFFICER','CHAPTER_OFFICER')

Comment: && ["SECTION_OFFICER","CHAPTER_OFFICER"].Contains(customer.CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE)